What is the intuition behind all invertible complex matrices being congruent?
Despite the proof being quite straightforward i found the fact that two symetric matrices over $\mathbb{C}$ are congruent as long as thier ranks are the same surprising.
In the language of bilinear forms this would suggest that there is only one symetric complex bilinear form of a given rank. Is there any good intuition, geometric or other behind this fact?
